# Where exactly is the line drawn for cheating?

Tags: cheats

I've been playing Skyrim quite regularly lately, and I find myself using console commands to speed up time to make tedious tasks go quicker. Yet I don't simply spawn in a million gold because that's "cheating". It got me thinking, is it cheating to speed up tedious tasks?

I'm sure we can all agree that spawning in 1,000,000 gold is definitely cheating, but what about speeding time so mining iron doesn't take so freaking long (WHY Bethesda... why)? What about resetting an area using console commands so I don't have to sleep for 30 days (equivalent of around 10 real minutes of waiting). Speaking of that, is sleeping for 30 days straight even cheating?

Where is the line drawn?

Comment: This is more an opinion rather than a question that can be helped.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: It's a single-player game. Do whatever you want. By the way, sleeping goes faster if you type `tfc` first in the console. Type it again after you're done sleeping.

Comment: Um, there are better ways to mine than pressing the "Use" key.  Try swinging pickaxes manually.  You can get the One Hand perks and get "dual wielding", dual right hand pickaxe, left hand whatever, use Elemental Fury level 3, then you can mine each vein in about 1 second.

Comment: Question is impossible to answer, but I'd say any means of gaining an advantage that are not through pure "natural"/intended gameplay are cheating. That includes a lot of mods.

Comment: Generally speaking, doing anything not intended by the game mechanics is cheating. So, if you use the console in any way whatsoever to do anything, that's cheating. That being said, it's a single-player game, so if you are having more fun cheating, then cheat away. Cheating is only 'wrong' if you are cheating other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people think that gaining access to anything through commands or non standard ways is cheating.

Some will argue that providing yourself with little buffs for the a games lack of balance or to make it easier are fine, however spawning in 100's of minions just kills the game for you.

TL;DR - it iss where the game no longer becomes fun for you because you have ruined it by your own actions.